# Problema con tabla dinamica al eliminar

Tags: jquery

Tengo una tabla dinamica a la que agrego un registro desde un boton agregar, y en la fila aparece el confirmar, de ser asi se inserta la fila con un bootn editar y eliminar. Para eliminar tengo un mensaje de confirmacion pero aparece una vez por cada registro que hay en la tabla, supongo porque estoy usando clases, de que manera podria usar un id?

```js
$("#agregarc").click(function(){
  
    var datoscheque='<tr><td><div>'+
    '<select id="bancos"><option value"=0">Seleccione<option></select></div></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nrocuenta" placeholder="CtaBancaria"/>'
    +'</td>'+
    
    '<td><input type="text"class="form-control" id="titular" placeholder="Titular"/></td>'+
  +'<div>'+'<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="CUITCHEQUE" placeholder="CUIT"/></td>'+
  '<td><input type="text"class="form-control" id="Importe" placeholder="Son pesos"/></td>'
    +
    '<td><input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechacobro"placeholder="Deposito el:"/></td>'+
 
    '<td><button id="acreditar" class="btn btn-primary"><span id="acreditar" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button></td></tr>';


var acreditado = ($("#cheques tbody tr:last").find('button#acreditar').length === 0 || $("#cheques tbody tr").length === 0);
    if(acreditado){
       $(datoscheque).appendTo("#cheques");
       listarbancos(); 
    }else
    alert('complete e ingrese el registro actual');
  
  $("#acreditar").click(function(){
  
    var Banco=$("#bancos").val();
    var Importe=$("#Importe").val();

    var nroCuenta=$("#nrocuenta").val();
    var titular=$("#titular").val();
    var fechacobro=$("#fechacobro").val();
   var CUIT=$("#CUITCHEQUE").val();
    
    var cobrado=0;
    var d = new Date();
    var fecharecibo=d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getDate();
   
    
  /*   $.ajax({
                                                        type: "POST",
                                                        url: "//localhost/gestionweb/includes/php/ingresacheque.php",
                                                        data: { "idbanco":Banco,"idc":idcliente,"num":nroCuenta,"fechar":fecharecibo,"fechac":fechacobro,"importe":Importe,"titular":titular,"cuenta":nroCuenta,"cobrado":cobrado,"CUIT":CUIT},
                                                   
                                            
                                                        error: function(){
                                                            alert("error petición ajax");
                                                           
                                                        },
                                                        
                                                        success: function(data){
                                                         
                                                            console.log(data); */
   

      
    
    var Bancot=$("#bancos").find('option:selected').text();
    var nroCuenta=$("#nrocuenta").val();
    var titular=$("#titular").val();
    var fechacobro=$("#fechacobro").val();
    
    var importe=$("#Importe").val();
 
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(0)").html(Bancot);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(1)").html(nroCuenta);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(2)").html(titular);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(3)").html(CUIT);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(4)").html(importe);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(5)").html(fechacobro);
 $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(6)").html('<td><button class="btn btn-primary "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td><td>'+
'<button class="eliminar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td><td>');



 $(".eliminar").on("click",function(){
    var opcionche = confirm("¿Desea eliminar cheque?");
    if (opcionche == true) {
   
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();} 

});
});
});
```

Comment: No entendi muy bien tu planteamiento, dices que solo te sale una vez el confirm y cuando le das a otra fila no te sale?

Comment: Puedes insertar el evento `onclick` directamente en cada fila y hacer una función aparte

Comment: si hay 3 registros aparece 3 veces, y con el ultimo no funciona

Comment: intenta cambiando $(".eliminar") por  $(".eliminar:last") o sino ponle $(".eliminar").off().on( y lo que sigue